# Entering an if statement, but it shouldn't / entering false if statement

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This is in vbscript on an .asp page.

```
  number1 = GETFIELDSFROMSQL(sqlRequest, "MaxLoan")

  response.write "number1: " & number1
  response.write "number2: " & Session("number2")

        If number1 > Session("number2") Then
        response.write "TESTTTTTTTT entered the if statement!"
            number1 = Session("number2")
        End If
```

number 1 prints to the screen as `10000`

number 2 prints to the screen as `30000`

But for some reason, it's entering the if statement and I don't think it should.

What are some reasons vbscript might enter a false if statement?

Comment: What are the datatypes for number1 and Session("number2")? Comparing an int to a string can give the wrong result.

Comment: Thank you! I used VarType and found that to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatype for number1 is an int and Session("number2") is a string then the expression can give the wrong result.